# can't shard a collection on mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a db ("mydb") on mongo that contains 2 collections (c1 and c2). c1 is already hash sharded. I want to shard a second collection the same way. I get the following error :

```
use mydb
sh.shardCollection("mydb.c2", {"LOG_DATE": "hashed"})
    {
"proposedKey" : {
    "LOG_DATE" : "hashed"
},
"curIndexes" : [
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "mydb.c1",
        "name" : "_id_"
    }
],
"ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "please create an index that starts with the shard key before sharding."
```

So I did

```
db.c2.ensureIndex({LOG_DATE: 1})
sh.shardCollection("mydb.c2", {"LOG_DATE": "hashed"})
```

Same error but it shows the new index.

```
"proposedKey" : {
    "LOG_DATE" : "hashed"
},
"curIndexes" : [
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "mydb.c2",
        "name" : "_id_"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "LOG_DATE" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "mydb.c2",
        "name" : "LOG_DATE_1"
    }
],
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "please create an index that starts with the shard key before sharding."
```

Just to be sure, I run :

```
db.system.indexes.find()
{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "_id" : 1 }, "ns" : "mydb.c1", "name" : "_id_" }
{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "timestamp" : "hashed" }, "ns" : "mydb.c1", "name" : "timestamp_hashed" }
{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "_id" : 1 }, "ns": "mydb.c2", "name" : "_id_" }
{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "LOG_DATE" : 1 }, "ns" : "mydb.c2", "name" : "LOG_DATE_1" }
```

I try again the same commands on admin and it fails with the same error.

Then I tried on admin without "hashed" and it worked.

```
db.runCommand({shardCollection: "mydb.c2", key: {"LOG_DATE": 1}})
```

Problem : now my collection is sharded on something that is not hashed and I can't change it (error : "already sharded")

1. What was wrong with what I did ?
2. How can I fix this ?

Thanks in advance

Thomas

Comment: `ensureIndex({LOG_DATE:"hashed"})` http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-hashed-index/ , you cannot change your shard key, you will need to redo the collection

Comment: I did remove collection and redid my collection, but I can't shard it again. How do I remove sharding information before doing collection.remove() ?

Comment: removeShard should be able to get rid of the metadata: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/removeShard/#dbcmd.removeShard

Comment: I don't want to remove the shard because other collections are on it

Comment: Have you looked through: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/sharding/#can-i-change-the-shard-key-after-sharding-a-collection

Comment: They don't give the answer

Comment: Another thing I wanted to add : index : "hashed" is not that great because I want to index a date and make >= queries. There is no way to make this + hash shard on that ? (mongodb's doc preconizes not to shard over a monotonically increasing field)

Comment: It says on that page the best way to change the shard key, read the entire section

Comment: there is no removeCollection - you want to use db.collection.drop()

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem initially was that you did not have a hashed index what you proposed to use for sharding this is the error message is about. After the first error message, when you created an index which is

```
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "LOG_DATE" : 1
    },
    "ns" : "mydb.c2",
    "name" : "LOG_DATE_1"
}
```

You still just have an ordinary index which is not a hashed one. If you would do this :

```
db.c2.ensureIndex({LOG_DATE: "hashed"})
```

Instead of this :

```
db.c2.ensureIndex({LOG_DATE: 1})
```

Than would be a hashed index. As you can see in the output of the db.system.indexes.find() on the other collection you have a hashed index for the timestamp i assume this is the shard key for that collection.

So if you have no data in the c2 collection:

```
db.c2.drop()
db.createCollection('c2')
db.c2.ensureIndex({LOG_DATE: "hashed"})
sh.shardCollection("mydb.c2", {"LOG_DATE": "hashed"})
```

This will work properly.

Comment: In short if we have a hashed index we can hash shard on the underlying key, and if it is not hashed we can't hash shard on it. But why is that ? Im trying to have a mental image of how indexes work/are implemented in mongodb and I can't figure out why this is enforced this way

Comment: It is like it is. You have to have an index on the collection and this index will be the base of the sharding (data will be partitioned through this index's key ranges). Read the docs about, that Sammaye suggested in the comments to your question.